# Adding empty fields in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

```
// Add product data to DB.
 AddProducts products = new AddProducts();
 bool addSuccess = products.AddProduct(AddProductName.Text, AddProductDescription.Text, AddSubHeading1.Text, AddSubInfo1.Text, AddSubHeading2.Text, AddSubInfo2.Text, AddSubHeading3.Text, AddSubInfo3.Text, AddSubHeading4.Text, AddSubInfo4.Text, AddSubHeading5.Text, AddSubInfo5.Text, DropDownAddCategory.SelectedValue, ProductImage.FileName);
 if (addSuccess)
 {
    // Reload the page.
    string pageUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Count() - Request.Url.Query.Count());
                Response.Redirect(pageUrl + "?ProductAction=add");
 }
 else
 {
     LabelAddStatus.Text = "Unable to add new product to database.";
 }
}
else
{
    LabelAddStatus.Text = "Unable to accept file type.";
}
```

I am creating a website for my employer that has an admin page that allows the user to add products, I have tried a few methods now but I have not been able to enter empty fields into the database through this page. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please show `Product` model

Comment: What happens, actually? Do you get an exception? I'm assuming that you're getting false for `addSuccess`. In that case we would be interested to see the code of `AddProduct`.

Comment: here is the code from AddProducts.cs  var myProduct = new Product();
myProduct.ProductName = ProductName;
myProduct.Description = ProductDesc;
myProduct.SubHeading1 = SubHeading1;
myProduct.SubInfo1 = SubInfo1;
 myProduct.SubHeading2 = SubHeading2;
myProduct.SubInfo2 = SubInfo2;
myProduct.SubHeading3 = SubHeading3;
myProduct.SubInfo3 = SubInfo3;
myProduct.SubHeading4 = SubHeading4;
myProduct.SubInfo4 = SubInfo4;
myProduct.SubHeading5 = SubHeading5;
myProduct.SubInfo5 = SubInfo5;
myProduct.ImagePath = ProductImagePath;
myProduct.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ProductCategory);

Answer (score 0):

Can check whether the string is null and give a  ' ' value using

```
AddProductName?.Text?? " " //in C#6.0
```

or you can use

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddproductName.Text))
{
  AddproductName.Text=" ";
}
```

and then try inserting into the database

if it is null, also check if the database is allowed to take empty or null values.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, the database does allow nulls however when trying this solution I keep getting the same exception.